# Is feedback really recorded when someone with too few reputation points upvotes/downvotes a question?

Tags: support

I currently have only 13 reputation points, so I'm unable to upvote or downvote any questions or answers. But when I try to up- or downvote something it tells me that although I'm not qualified for such activities, my feedback has been recorded. Is this feedback *really* recorded somewhere, and does it make any difference, or is it there just to make me feel good?

Comment: @vandench No, it doesn't. Feedback is just recorded in the database, and is more or less only visible to high-rep users via 10k tools, or anyone via SEDE. Downvotes aren't stored to be automatically applied later though

Comment: The feedback is definitely recorded because there are 10k pages showing it, but I am not sure whether it actually has an impact on anything.

Comment: Alright then. I'm surprised they would track the feedback, and then never make it publicly visible, even when you earn the voting privilege, given that the "feedback" is specifically for the community at large.

Comment: @vandench the feedback *is* public... just to a "small set of public". Namely people with >10k reputation.

Comment: *"Is this feedback *really* recorded somewhere"* Yes, but not shown except in very obscure places. *"and does it make any difference"* Mostly, it does not.  There are some pages available to some users with underrated/overrated/most helpful/least helpful, but...I doubt anyone is doing much of anything with them.  *"or is it there just to make me feel good?"* In effect, this is the primary purpose.

Comment: @Sabito錆兎standswithUkraine As mentioned by Zoe, [it's "public" to _everyone_ through SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1405340/), just... buried, since it's not displayed anywhere